# C struct instance is missing members after copying it to Swift

Tags: c, swift, linux, struct

I'm using C's [`inotify`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) library, through a wrapper in Swift. The idea is to provide a *Swift Package Manager* library that gives basic File System events support in Linux.

Almost everything works. Except that here, I can't seem to be able to copy the `inotify_event` member **`name`**:

```
let bufferLength = Int(MemoryLayout<inotify_event>.size + NAME_MAX + 1)
let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>.allocate(capacity: bufferLength)

var fileSystemEvent : FileSystemEvent?
var currentIndex: Int = 0
let readLength = read(Int32(self.fileDescriptor), buffer, bufferLength)

while currentIndex < readLength {
  var event = withUnsafePointer(to: &buffer[currentIndex]) {
    return $0.withMemoryRebound(to: inotify_event.self, capacity: 1) {
      return $0.pointee
    }
  }
  if event.len > 0 {
     fileSystemEvent = FileSystemEvent(
       watchDescriptor: WatchDescriptor(event.wd),
       name: "", //String(cString: event.name),
       mask: event.mask,
       cookie: event.cookie,
       length: event.len
     )
  }
  currentIndex += MemoryLayout<inotify_event>.stride + Int(event.len)
}
```

I would want to do:

`name: String(cString: event.name)`, but **then the compiler throws an error:**

```
           `value of type 'inotify_event' has no member 'name'`
```

I can't find any clues as to why this happens, or as to how I can access the `name` member. Here is the struct's declaration in `inotify.h`:

```
/*
 * struct inotify_event - structure read from the inotify device for each event
 *
 * When you are watching a directory, you will receive the filename for events
 * such as IN_CREATE, IN_DELETE, IN_OPEN, IN_CLOSE, ..., relative to the wd.
 */
struct inotify_event {
    __s32       wd;     /* watch descriptor */
    __u32       mask;       /* watch mask */
    __u32       cookie;     /* cookie to synchronize two events */
    __u32       len;        /* length (including nulls) of name */
    char        name[0];    /* stub for possible name */
};
```

What's going on here?

*Thanks in advance :)*

PS: [here's my full project](https://github.com/felix91gr/FileSystemWatcher), if you need more information.

Comment: Can you include the declaration of the inotify_event struct from its ".h" file in your source example?

Comment: You'd better edit your question and include the definition of `inotify_event` into it. Not all readers try to go inside the link, and the definition of the struct is the key info for your issue.

Comment: @felix91gr great work on your fork of my repo! stumbled upon this problem myself and just left it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` field is defined as a zero-length array:

```
char        name[0];    /* stub for possible name */
```

and those are not
imported into Swift. A possible solution is to compute the offset to the
start of the name string within the received buffer:

```
 fileSystemEvent = FileSystemEvent(
   watchDescriptor: WatchDescriptor(event.wd),
   name: String(cString: buffer + currentIndex + MemoryLayout<inotify_event>.size),
   mask: event.mask,
   cookie: event.cookie,
   length: event.len)
```

Comment: @martin-r could you point me to the documentation about zero-length arrays not being imported into swift? I'm trying to modify my inotify wrapper so that the name will be accessible as an optional attribute of a swift struct and I'm doing all the research I can to learn about swift c interop